# When take instance class changes effect in GAE apps?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I recently changed the class from F1 to F2 but did not notice that existing instances were restarted. So, I shutdown all existing instances manually hoping that all new instances will be F2s. **How can I tell in which instance class a running instance is?** I cannot find anything in the instances UI or the logs to confirm the instance class of a running instance. According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings)

> You can change the current frontend instance class for your app at any time. Python and Go apps automatically get the new instance class that you choose. A Java app must be restarted to get the new instance class.

How can a **Java app be restarted** on GAE? Does that mean that only new instances will be affected by the change? Or do I even have to redeploy my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart the instances for the instance class change to take effect. A quick way to do that is to hit the shutdown button for each running instance in the Instance page in the Admin Console.

There does not appear to be a way to determine the class of a running instance from the API or environment variables.